# WordPress theme - Translations from .PO & .MO files are not working

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization

I've been trying to translate a WordPress theme for days with no success, no matter what I try, the `_e` translate function doesn't work and the strings just stay the same as they are in the .POT file.

What I've done so far:

- Loaded the text domain from the *languages* folder from inside the theme inside **functions.php**

```
function theme_setup() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'domain', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );
```

- Wrapped the strings I want to translate in the `_e()` function, including the text domain.

`<?php _e( 'Află mai multe', "domain" ); ?>`

- The *languages* folder includes a .POT file generated with EazyPo that includes all strings that are inside `_e()` functions together with an English translation of my strings with .PO and .MO files called `en.PO` and `en.MO` respectively.

[image]

- Switched the language of the website in WordPress General Settings to English.[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I see from your code is that you action is calling the wrong function.

You should change this: `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'optimrent_setup' );`
To this: `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );`

Because the second parameter to add_action is to what function the callback should be. So in that code you have above, should display some sort of error if you don't have the function `optimrent_setup`

Comment: Really sorry about that, I edited the function name before writing it in the post because I didn't want to reveal the actual name. No biggie though. Anyway, I am giving it the correct parameter in the actual code and I'm going to edit the OP now to reflect that.

Comment: ah okey :) one more thing you can try to change your file names for the translations. So instead of just "en" you change it to "en_US" to .mo and .po files